# Breaking angular modules to different projects with same configs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface, micro-frontend

I have an angular project with around 20 different modules. Now for a piece of code changes in one module, the whole project needs to be deployed.
I want to break my modules in different projects for separate deployment.

I thought of having separate angular projects but then will have to duplicate authorization,translation and many of the codes in each project.

Any idea how i can achieve separate code base and deployment of modules but with having common services (interceptors,authorization& & translation)

Answer (score 1):

**Angular-libraries**

You can use angular libraries where you can separate your moduels to pacakge more like a NPM package and you can even reuse it to different projects

Each libraries act and maintained as a separate app

please refer : https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries